# why new (custom) module in django app is not recognized?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I wanted to simply add some python files to one of my apps, in order to split code. If I create 'main.py' inside my app folder and import it from views.py (for istance) then I get:

```
File "/home/francesco/django-projects/my-env/my-projects/my-app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

The file structure is:

```
my-app/
|..
|views.py
|main.py
```

I imported main.py with `import main`

I couldn't find anything online, I don't know if it can't be done (if so, is there a workaround?) or if I'm doing something wrong (if so, what's the correct way?).
I'm using django 4.1

Thanks

Comment: Of course it can be done :) Share how you do import `main` and your file structure (structure can be as image).

Comment: `from . import main`? The file is probably not in the `PYTHONPATH` which is why you can't import it directly.

Comment: Django is introspective, don't break the pattern, read the tutorial, complete the settings.py and your app will be loaded when setup is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved changing `import main` to `from . import main`